# How to show image input type file button on panel (summernote)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

How to show image input type file button on panel (summernote) ?

this is my summernote

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zr87kuh2/4/
```

Normally when i want to insert image to summernote, First we have to click on image button

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehoZ.png
```

and then it's will show input type file button.

I want to know, How can i show input type file button on panel summernote ?